# Restricting users to printers and shares in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I am relatively new to Active Directory and am having trouble getting my mind around the following scenario:

- I have a set of users in the HR department
- I have a set of users in the Marketing department
- There are a couple of users that are part of both HR and Marketing
- I am setting up a shared folder for only he Marketing department to use
- I am setting up a shared printer for only the HR department to use

I originally thought I would do the following:

1. Add the HR users to the HR OU
2. Add the Marketing users to the Marketing OU
3. Add some users to both OUs
4. Apply a Group Policy to the HR OU for only those users to print to that printer
5. Apply a Group Policy to the Marketing OU for only those users to access the folder.

However, I am stuck at step 3 above, because it seems that I cannot add users to more than one OU. I have thought about using a Domain Local Group instead of an OU, but then I think I cannot apply a GPO to a Group.

I know there is a way to do this. Where am I failing in my understanding and what is a good approach for dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

A user object can only be in one OU. However, it's possible to [apply a GPO to a security group](https://www.itprotoday.com/security/how-can-i-apply-group-policy-security-group):

> 1. Select the GPO from the list and click Properties
> 2. Select the Security tab
> 3. Modify the permissions so that only the required users have the read and apply privileges and Administrators who need to modify the
>      GPO have read and write.

Requirements:

- You must apply the GPO for both OUs.
- All required users from both OUs must also be members of the security group.